# Continue Ansible Playbook after reboot

Tags: unity-game-engine, vagrant, ansible, reboot

Situation: On a Windows host machine, I want to install a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16 + some dev tools. For that, I use Vagrant and VirtualBox (both on the Windows host) and a **local** Ansible on the vm.

Problem: After the vm is installed, it should show the unity login in Virtual Box, so that a user can login there and start working. However, the installation of unity (and the upgrade task) seem to require a restart. Furthermore, when I run `vagrant up` or `vagrant provision` a second time, unity is already installed, so it should NOT reboot again.

Summarized question: How can I reboot my VM *if needed* and continue provisioning after that in a vagrant + local ansible setup?

My scripts so far:

---

Vagrantfile (on Windows host)

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    # create a Ubuntu 16 LTS box
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
        vb.gui = true

        # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
        vb.memory = "4096"
    end

    config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    end
end
```

playbook.yml (on Windows host and transferred to Ubuntu guest)

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks: 
  - name: Update apt cache
    apt: update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=36000

  - name: Upgrade to latest version
    apt: upgrade=dist autoremove=yes
    become: yes

  - name: Add local user with pwd
    user: name=<someuser> password=<someencryptedpwd>
    become: true

  - name: Install Ubuntu Desktop
    apt: name=ubuntu-desktop
    become: true
```

P.S. If have seen multiple ansible solutions for that, but they assume that ansible runs on the host. Not possible in this situation due to a Windows host.

Comment: I will leave the question open for now, since it seems that there is no 100% answer there for now

Answer (score 4):

There's existing vagrant plugin https://github.com/aidanns/vagrant-reload which can help you run a reboot in the middle of a provisioning sequence

make sure to install the plugin

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-reload
```

in your Vagrantfile, your provisioning will look like

```
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook_pre_reboot.yml"
end
config.vm.provision :reload
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook_post_reboot.yml"
end
```

You'll need to split your playbook to run the task to be run before the reboot and another playbook for task to be run after.

This command is added to the provisioner sequence, so this address the fact that you need to reboot the VM during the provisioning run. Once the VM has been fully provisioned, it will not be called again so `vagrant up` a second time will not reboot the VM.

However as it is a part of your provisioning run, specifically calling the provisioner to run (`vagrant up --provisioner` or `vagrant provision`) will call this provisioner to run. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/aidanns/vagrant-reload/issues/2) to have possibility to set condition on this provisioner but this is not yet addressed so calling vagrant provisioner to run will always call this reboot to run.

Comment: Now, the problem is how can `playbook_pre_reboot.yml` give feedback to make this step conditional to meet the OP's requirement "*so it should NOT reboot again*"...

Comment: @techraf well there's no condition for this "reboot provisioner" so once you add it in your Vagrantfile it will be added to your provisioning sequence, thus it will be called whenever you specifically call the provisioners to be (`vagrant up --provision` or `vagrant provision`) I agree its may not be ideal if you plan to run many update on the provisioning part but usually you're not doing many call to `vagrant provision` once the VM has been fully provisionned

Comment: I agree it shouldn't be necessary, but OP clearly specified it in the question: "*when I run [...] `vagrant provision` a second time [...]  it should NOT reboot again*".

Comment: clear it solves 50% of the request (`vagrant up` after the initial provisioning will not reboot the VM) but specifically calling the provisioner will reboot the VM. will edit my post to make this clear. afaik you can't even script that, if you boot your `reboot` or `shutdown -r now` command in your script directly it will reboot the machine but stops the the provisioning to run, you must run within context to plugin.

Comment: so far, reboot is possible, but not on condition. How about the other option? Could I set up the ansible playbook in a way that runs it, then triggers the reboot, and then continues to run? The problem here might be, that we are rebooting the machine on which ansible is running, which is why it sounds more like a vagrant task.